# If I already have code for search function in javascript, how can i make it look nicer?

Tags: css

This is my code for "search" on my site. How do I make the search presentation look better?
I want to be able to manipulate how it looks, but I don't know how to do that with this code.

```
String auth = (String)session.getAttribute("auth");
    //if (auth != null) {
        out.write( "<table>");
        out.write( "<tr>");
        out.write( "<form action=\"SearchServlet\" method=\"get\"> ");
        out.write( "<input type=\"text\" name=\"query\" size=\"60\" >"); 
        out.write( "</tr>");
        out.write( "<tr>");
        out.write( "<td><input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"Search\"></td>");  
        out.write( "</form> </tr> </table>");
    //}
```

Comment: add css. use bootstrap.

Comment: Wrap the table in the form btw - your html is invalid - you are also missing a TD, and tables are no longer used for styling. Use a fieldset if you have more than one field

Comment: @argentum47 yes, so how do i do that?

Comment: @mplungjan i have all the necessary parts to make this work, and it is for a table for a catalog on my page. so how do i wrap it in the form?

Comment: @CodenameSand if you want to do it yourself, add a css file , add some styling and include it in your html in the link tag, if you want something fast and framework-ish include bootstrap's css and js in your link and script tags.

Comment: Format is `<form><table><tr><td><input.../></td><td><input.../></td></tr></table></form>` also see https://www.google.nl/search?q=css+search+form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is simply add a class to the table

```
out.write( "<table class='myclass'>");
```

That way you can manipulate the whole table in CSS like so

```
.myclass { background-color: blue; }
.myclass td { background-color: red; }
.myclass input { background-color: green; }
```

If you have more than one TD or INPUT you might want to consider giving them their own class names so that you can differentiate between them.

```
out.write( "<td class='mytd1'></td>");
out.write( "<td class='mytd2'></td>");

.mytd1 { background-color: red; }
.mytd1 { background-color: blue; }
```

By the way, you can also give a class name to the input.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'class' to the table and use CSS to manipulate the search using this class name.